Sign in - Google accounts (choose a account) - Cant seem to be able to click the account (python selenium)
Its the page where you choose which account to login with on a website. I have a hard time clicking the account element. I have no idea if im writing the wrong path or it has something to do with a new window/tab opening. I want to click the first account. I've tried every way, xpath, css, js, class name, id. Nothing seems to work. Would appreciate if someone figures this out, it would help alot. Im new to this so i dont know much.

you may not want to post that link... could have a sensitive token or id in there.  I'd check for shadow-dom, but Google is pretty strict with bot-detection for any login stuff.

removed the link, thank you for telling me. I've already logged into youtube in the automation, but this time it just doesn't seem to work.

youtube is a little different in that 1 google account can be used on multiple sites, while the reverse is not true for youtube account.  (it's tied to google nowadays, but not equal to the google login)  Think of Google as the authentication server and youtube as a site that uses them as such.  What you are seeing is from Google but you wouldn't necessarily see that unless multiple youtube accounts tied to single Google account.
